# SQLite JDBC 3.30.1 (latest) does not support java.time

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, java-time

SQLite JDBC 3.30.1 (latest) does not support java.time. e.g.,

create table Foo (id TEXT, time1 NUMERIC, time2 NUMERIC);

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Foo(id, time1, time2) values (1, ?, ?)");
stmt.setParameter(1, LocalDate.now());
stmt.setParameter(2, LocalTime.now());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Success. Now try to retrieve the row:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("select id, time1, time2 from Foo");
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();

resultSet.getObject(2, java.time.LocalDate.class)
resultSet.getObject(2, java.time.LocalTime.class)
```

throw

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
```

Any one faces the same problem and has a solution?

Comment: What is your question? If you want to report a bug, report it to the maintainer of the JDBC driver you're using.

Comment: any one faces the same problem and has a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Surprising as it seems, `resultSet.getObject(2, java.time.LocalDate.class)` does indeed throw a `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`. However, you can use `.getString` to retrieve the String representation and then use `.parse` to convert it afterward:

```java
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select id, time1, time2 from Foo");
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();

String ldString = resultSet.getString(2);
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(ldString);
String ltString = resultSet.getString(3);
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(ltString);

System.out.println(ld);  // 2020-03-22
System.out.println(lt);  // 15:53:49.284
```

Comment: The column type for LocalDate/LocalTime should be TEXT instead of NUMERIC?

Comment: SQLite is a bit unusual that way. Column types are not strictly enforced; it tends to consider a column type declaration as an ["affinity"](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) rather than a hard and fast rule. That may explain why they are unable (or perhaps just unwilling) to support `java.time` objects, as they can't count on column typing to let them know what to expect when they retrieve a particular value.